# Pagination 404 Not Found child page

Tags: pagination, url-rewriting, 404-error

I have a page *Heemtijdinghen* displaying custom posts (post_type=artikel) paginated. The page is a child page of page *Publicaties*:
`/publicaties/heemtijdinghen/`

When navigating to e.g. page 2 a 404 Not Found is thrown:
`/publicaties/heemtijdinghen/page/2/ => 404 Not Found`

However, pagination does work correctly when I make the child page a parent page:
`/heemtijdinghen/page/2/ => OK`

I have no clue how to do the rewrite:

```
add_filter('init', 'plugin_name_add_rewrite_rules');

function plugin_name_add_rewrite_rules() {
  add_rewrite_rule('publicaties/heemtijdinghen/(.?.+?)(/[0-9]+)?/?$', 'index.php?post_type=artikel', 'top');
  add_rewrite_rule('publicaties/heemtijdinghen/([^/]+)(/[0-9]+)?/?$', 'index.php?post_type=artikel&paged=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
```

Help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

does your query have this

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
  'posts_per_page' => 3,
  'paged' => $paged
);

query_posts($args);
```

see documentation about pagination http://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination

Comment: Yes: `$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
 $args = array(
  'post_type' => 'artikel',
  'paged' => $paged
 );`

Comment: save your permalink again that will work

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not do the trick.

Comment: I dropped the custom URL format I used on my Custom Post Type. Now using the normal WordPress URL-logic: it works.

Comment: thats good know